# Could we get a better example question for the new /about?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, status-completed

As some have already seen, the [/about page](https://askubuntu.com/about) on main has changed dramatically. It's fancy now with all the moving parts and visual examples, but there is one thing that feels kinda odd about it.

## The example is not a good one

The example currently given, as seen in the following screenshot, is a slightly modified version of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210870/).

[image: screenshot from /about]

While I fully understand that the examples need to be kept short so they don't take up too much space, the given answer is pretty much link-only and would be deserving of the "Nothing but a URL (and isn't spam)" pro-forma comment:

> Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

The /about section is intended to show new users what this site is about, and introduce them to the way the site works. Shouldn't we, then, encourage good answers with a good example, rather than bad ones?

## So, this question boils down to two points:

- Why was *this* specific question chosen, or what makes a question eligible for being the example question on /about?
- Shall we replace the current example question, and with what other question?

Comment: as per shog9's answer, i present  http://askubuntu.com/questions/93671/should-i-restart-after-updating-my-system as a viable option.

Comment: I think jrg's question would fit.  It might even be useful to new user, where I doubt the Nexus one would apply to most.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are certain requirements for the question there, due to the space available and the need for at least *two* answers that will fit (one which must have a comment on it).

[Here are some eligible questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/92077/aboutable-questions). Pick a better one!

Keep in mind, the posts displayed on /about will be chosen to not have any lists, images, code, or headers. So if you pick a question that has one great (but long and detailed and heavily-formatted) answer and two short, crappy ones, the short ones will be the answers displayed. I realize this often is not an ideal way to show off the site's expertise and preferred style of answering, but it's currently necessary to avoid overwhelming the actual content of /about.

Currently set to [jrg's suggestion](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5777/could-we-get-a-better-example-question-for-the-new-about#comment8442_5777)